# Hadoop Cluster setup (Fully distributed mode)

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am setting up hadoop on a multinode cluster, and I have a few questions:

1. Will it be ok to have `NameNode` and `ResourceManager` on the same machine?
2. Which will be the best role for a master system, `NameNode`, `ResourceManager` Or `DataNode/NodeManager`?.
3. I have a master and 3 slave machines. The slaves file on the master machine has the following entries:

   ```
   master
   slave1
   slave2
   slave3
   ```

Do I have to place this same slaves file in all of the slave machines? Or should I remove the first line (master) and then place it in the slave machines?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, at least in small clusters those two should be running in the master node.
2. Check answer 1. Master node can have also for example SecondaryNamenode and JobHistoryServer
3. No, the slaves file is only on the master node. If you have the master node in the slaves file, it means that the master node acts also as a datanode. Especially in small clusters that's totally fine. The slaves file essentially tells which on nodes the datanode processes are started.

Slave nodes should only run DataNode and NodeManager. But this is all handled by Hadoop if the configurations are correct - you can just check which processes are running after starting the cluster from the master node. Master node basically takes care of everything and you "never" need to manually connect to the slaves for any configurations.

My answer is meant for small clusters, probably in bigger "real" clusters the server responsibilities are even more separated.

Comment: thanks for your response Lauri. Is it necessary to map the IP and Name on the hosts file on Slaves ? Just like I did on master machine ?

Comment: According to my experience, yes. I have the same hosts file contents on all servers.

Answer (score 1):

For fully understand the multinode cluster concept follow this link-- http://bradhedlund.com/2011/09/10/understanding-hadoop-clusters-and-the-network/

and for implemtation of multinode cluster step vise follow this link --
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/

May these links help you

Comment: I think this better be posted as a comment